# How to mock main

Tags: java, testing, program-entry-point, powermock

My class Under Test access Main itself (Main.doSomething)
I would like to mock Main class to avoid setting up the whole process with all the hasltle
how can I do so?

I am using Powermock with Mockito.

Comment: Consider adding more detail to your question. There is very little here to give a directed, informative answer.

Answer (score 3):

`Main` is not a reserved word for a class in Java. It means you can test like any other class. It depends if `doSomething` is `static` and/or `final` or not.

Comment: +1 Note that PowerMock can mock final and static methods and classes by using its own classloader which manipulates the byte code as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that having to mock static methods is a bad practice (your method shouldn't be static if it is supposed to be mocked: *if the class is difficult to test – refactor the class* -- http://monkeyisland.pl/2008/01/14/mockito/).

Nevertheless, here is how you do it with powermock:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Main.class);
PowerMockito.when(Main.doSomething()).thenReturn(something);
```

Here the documentation: http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic

For mocking static members do:

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(Main.class, doSomething);
```

Comment: OK thanks. how can I mock static members and not only methods?

Comment: I don't know what kind of code you are dealing with and it scares me just to think about it. You can mock static member by doing: Whitebox.setInternalState(Main.class, doSomething); But you should really think about refactoring the code so you don't use any static member.

Answer (score 0):

A more powerful Mocking Framework is `JMockit`. It gives enhanced mocking and stubbing functionality.

CheckOut: `http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/`